# Multiplication and division break my code

Tags: python

When I do addition and subtraction my calculator works, when I divide and multiply it breaks completely. Comments on the code go more in depth

I've tried editing the numbers/ variables in the list, but if i fix for multiplication and division, it breaks addition and subtraction.

```
s=input('What would you like to calculate? ') 

index = s.find("-") #goes through the equation to find it, and numbers it

if index == -1: 
    index = s.find('+') 

elif index == -1: 
    index=s.find('*')

elif index == -1: 
    index = s.find('/') 
if index == -1: 
    index = s.find('+')

op = s[index] # defines index as op 
lp = len(s) #defines the length of it as lp

p1 = s[0:index] #set variable for beginning through the operator 

sign = s[index] #this defines the sign 

p2=s[index+1:lp]#this goes from the number past the sign to the end 

print(p1) #these three are just to visualize

print(sign) #each individual part of the equation

print(p2) #for + and - it shows each part correctly, for * or / doesn't 

if sign == '+': #this is all the code that does the math 
    ans = int(p1)+int(p2) #variable that is defined as the answer 

elif sign == '-': 
    ans = (int(p1)-int(p2)) 

elif sign == '*': 
    ans = (int(p1)*int(p2)) 

elif sign == '/': 
    ans = (int(p1)/int(p2)) 

else: 
    print ('I do not understand') 

print (p1,sign,p2,'=',ans) #for the user, visualizes equation
```

When i put in 2/2 i should get 1, but instead i get an error code. When i put a print statement in front of the separate variables, i should get 2
/
2
but instead i get something like:
2/
2
2/2
when i go and do it with addition i get
10
+
10
which is correct

Comment: Heya! Please do let us know exactly what error you're getting, including the line number. I suspect that your `elif` clauses are wrong: let's say you input `2/2`. The first `if` block would evaluate `True` to the first clause if there is no `-` in your output, and never check to see if it can find a `/`. Try changing `elif` to `if`!

Comment: your logic for finding the sign to use is very mixed up and incorrect. It looks like you're going to end up with `index` equal to `-1` whenever your expression doesn't include `+` or `-`, which will lead to an error when you use it as an index to calculate `op`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of errors in this code:

```
index = s.find("-") 

if index == -1: 
    index = s.find('+') 

elif index == -1: 
    index=s.find('*')

elif index == -1: 
    index = s.find('/') 
if index == -1: 
    index = s.find('+')
```

First, the `if` statement at the very bottom is a duplicate, so delete that right off.

Next, think about what the `elif` statement does. It is a short form of *else if,* which means that code like this:

```
if index == -1:
elif index == -1:
elif index == -1:
```

is automatically wrong. "If index is -1, else if index is -1, else if index is -1".

That **control flow** does not allow for any other statements to be executed between the `if` and the `elif`. The only way for a statement to be executed is when one of those conditions *matches,* and that would mean the evaluation of `elif/else` alternatives stopped due to the match.

I suspect that you had the bottom block (`if ... s.find('+')`) and that you inserted the other code trying to added extra operations. In reality, what you had before was working with the simple if statements. Just duplicate them for the other cases:

```
index = s.find('-')
if index == -1:
    index = s.find('+')
# Note: no ELSE here, just another 'if'
if index == -1:
    index = s.find('*')
if index == -1:
    index = s.find('/')
if index == -1:
    print("Ack! No operator found")
```

The difference here is that each `if` statement creates a *fork* in the control flow. But the next `if` statement brings both alternative branches back together: the second `if` gets run *regardless* of whether the first `if` was true or false.

Answer (score 0):

I think you wanted to do this

```
...
index = s.find("-") #goes through the equation to find it, and numbers it

if index == -1: 
    index = s.find('+') 

if index == -1: 
    index=s.find('*')

if index == -1: 
    index = s.find('/') 
if index == -1: 
    index = s.find('+')
...
```